# error: Compressor is abstract; cannot be instantiated Android

Tags: java, android, image, compression, abstract

I'm trying to compress an image using the [zetbaitsu/Compressor](https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor), I even saw an tutorial on youtube but I'm getting this error.

**error: Compressor is abstract; cannot be instantiated**

this is the code.

```
try{
              compressed=new Compressor(this).compressToBitmap(compressedFile);
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I implemented the last version.

```
implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
```

Can anyone help please?

Thanks ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import `id.zelory:compressor`. Compressor
In your Java file

Answer (score 0):

Change your import to this `import id.zelory.compressor.Compressor`

Now you van use the use `Compressor(context)`

Answer (score -1):

```
implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.1'
```

use this dependecies on your gradle
and import

```
import id.zelory.compressor.Compressor;
```

Answer (score -2):

*The version worked for me:*

```
implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.1'
```

*Version 2.1.1 in my case helped me and it works fine.*

Comment: Frank, please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English-only site](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).